# Three monitor gaming with two different video cards

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, intel-graphics, eyefinity

I have a Radeon 7450 HD with a DVI monitor connected and a Intel HD 4000 with a DVI and a VGA monitor connected on my machine. I'm running both of them with the three monitors extended in Windows 8.1, all working fine.

But I've been trying to do some three monitor gaming and technologies such as Eyefinity and Intel Collage Display, but it seems that they are only applied to the monitors connected to the card (I can use Collage Display with the two monitors on the Intel). Is there any way I can do three monitor gaming with my setup?

Answer (score 1):

> I've been trying to do some three monitor gaming and technologies
>   such as Eyefinity and Intel Collage Display, 
>   but it seems that they are only applied to the monitors connected to the card

True. To use eyefinity you would need to connect all the monitors in the eyefinity setup to AMD card(s). As far as I know that is also true for the Intel GPU.

However there is software which can combine different GPUs (even across brands) and present one GPU to the system. (See [Lucid Virtu](http://lucidlogix.com/support/faqs/)).  I have not found out if this 'virtual GPU' supports eyefinity like functionality. So the best I can offer is a 'maybe' for your current setup.

However, why not simply connect all three displays to the AMD card and use eyefinity? In my experience that works just fine and it is probably more stable than running a game across different brand/model GPU's.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe this is possible. If there is a solution for it, then it is far beyond the grasp of both Google and myself. You would require a special piece of software to actually have both the Intel and AMD technologies operating together as it is unlikely either of the technologies are compatible with each other.

As well, the performance of a discrete Radeon HD7450 is not only better than the Intel HD 4000, but it is also likely to pass more "graphics tests" than the integrated chip is. You'd likely have a weird situation where two of the monitors would out-perform the single monitor running off of the integrated chip as well.

I believe you can buy a special kind of hub (not a splitter) that can "add" another port to the discrete graphics card if that might work for you. This is about all of the information I can provide.